# viewWillDisappear isnt called in iOS 13.6

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

after updating of xCode and visual studio viewWillDisappear method isnt called in iOS 13.6. Whats may be a problem?

```
public abstract class BaseChildView<T> : MvxViewController<T> where T : MvxViewModel{ 
public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
        {
            if (NavigationController?.ViewControllers != null && !NavigationController.ViewControllers.Contains(this))
            {
                // Back button was pressed.  We know this is true because self is no longer
                // in the navigation stack, hide MvvmCross's navigation menu
                var messenger = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxMessenger>();
                messenger.Publish(new NavigationBarHiddenMessage(this, true));
            }
            base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);
        }
```

Comment: FWIW, `viewWillDisappear` is called in iOS 13.6, just like earlier iOS versions. So I suspect some other problem, such as how the view was instantiated and pushed on to the stack. Are you sure this `BaseChildView` class is being used like you think it is?

Comment: Also, I assume you are subclassing this `BaseChildView` for your actual view controller in question. Does that have a `ViewWillDisappear` of its own? If so, is it calling the `ViewWillDisappear` of its superclass?

Comment: method viewDidLoad from BaseChildView , for example,  is called in subclasses, but ViewWillDisappear is not, i cant understand whats the reason. Before updating of VS2019 and xCode all works right

Comment: I’d suggest you create a blank project and see if you can manifest the problem in that. If not, keep adding code from your project and re-test as you go along, until you can reproduce the problem. But right now, all you’re doing is showing us code that is apparently not getting called, and the problem likely rests elsewhere. But we need a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to help you.